# Image processing: get rid of components that touch the image boundary

Tags: image-processing

I strongly suspect that there should be a built-in solution to the following problem:

I have a binary image like this:

```
image = Binarize@ColorNegate@Graphics[{
     Disk[{0, 0}, 1],
     Disk[{-1.5, 1.5}, 0.5],
     Disk[{3, 1}, {1, 1.5}]
     }, PlotRange -> 3 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]
```

[image]

I want to process the components with functions like `MorphologicalComponents` and `ComponentMeasurements`. How can I exclude components that touch the image boundary?  In this example the partially cropped ellipse should be excluded.

Comment: I am almost certain I have seen options for this somewhere, but I can't seem to find it in the docs.

Comment: Use ```DeleteBorderComponents``` first to remove them?

Comment: @SHuisman Will you post an answer or will you vote to close as "easily found in the docs"? I really didn't find it, even knowing I've seenit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `DeleteBorderComponents` first to remove them:

```
image = DeleteBorderComponents[image]
```

There is also:

```
ComponentMeasurements[image, ... , #AdjacentBorderCount == 0 &]
```